# Copy and paste loop in Excel

Tags: macros, microsoft-excel-2016, copy-paste

In Excel I would like to have a macro which does the following 100 times:

Copy the range A1:F4
Paste to A7:F10, i.e. leaving two empty rows
Then copy A7:F10, i.e. copy what was just pasted
Paste to A13:F16, i.e. again leaving two empty rows
repeat 100 times

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

1; turn on developer ribbon

2; record copy selection, going to end of sheet, down another 2 rows all using 'relative refs'.

3; create a new macro to say something like this...

```
Dim I as integer
Set i = 0
Do
   Call {macro recorded}
Set i = i + 1
Loop while i < 101
End
```

I have pretty much guessed the syntax, using a phone so no checking... Hopefully its enough to get you started.